# Ant: How do I adjust memory settings when running a custom Ant task?

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant 1.8.2 with Java 6.  I have written a custom task for Ant.  How do I set JVM memory settings when this custom task is run?  The task resembles …

```
<target name="Selenium4" depends="checkout-selenium-tests">
    <taskdef name="SeleniumHTMLClient" classname="com.cm.systems.selenium.ant.SeleniumRunner">
            <classpath refid="selenium-classpath-ref" />
    </taskdef>

    <SeleniumHTMLClient … arguments …>
        ...
    </SeleniumHTMLClient>

</target>
```

How would I adjust the memory settings when executing the custom task?  Thanks,  - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the memory configuration for your particular task, unless you fork a new JVM to run that task. To set the memory configuration for the Ant job as a whole, use the `ANT_OPTS` environment variable. See the "running" section of the [Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html).